# NGINX UWSGI Permission Denied

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

**Using**:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Python 3.8.10
- not using virtualenv. Everything is installed globally.

I am trying to deploy a Django website on my VPS using **uwsgi** and **nginx** but I keep getting 502 error code. In nginx error.log file I have the following exception:
`*543 connect() to unix:/root/uwsgi/testproject.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream`

The project structure is as follows:

wsgi file: root/html/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py

uwsgi ini: root/uwsgi/sites/testproject.ini

socket: root/uwsgi/testproject.sock

**Note:** I have used the root user during the whole setup.

**testproject.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/root/html/testproject
wsgi-file=/root/html/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py
socket=/root/uwsgi/testproject.sock
chmod-socket=666
uid=www-data
gid=www-data

master=True
pidfile=/tmp/project-master.pid
vaccum=True
max-requests=5000
daemonize=/tmp/uwsgi.logs
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/testproject**

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name 85.31.237.228;

        location / {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/root/uwsgi/testproject.sock;
        }
}
```

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

I have switched between 666 and 644 for chmod param but nothing worked.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain uwsgi is running?

Answer (score 0):

Try `ls /root/uwsgi/testproject.sock` to see if the socket is created.
Run `ls -l /root/uwsgi/` to check who owns the .sock file.
Run `ls -l /root/` to see who owns uwsgi and make sure the www-data user has access to the .sock file. You can try to run uwsgi config as root and then see if it can work